# How to save matched part when use 'eval' in regular expression with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, eval

```
$search_32bit  = '80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66)';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'A0 B0 C0 \1\2';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

$search_32bit  = '60 71 C3 (\S{10}) (CC 55 66)';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'D0 E0 F0 \1\2';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

        @repls_32 = (
                [ $search_32bit, $replace_32bit],
    [ $search_32bit_2, $replace_32bit_2],
                );

foreach my $r (@repls_32) {
    
    $s_sign = eval "\$hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/i";
    
}
```

My question is ,how can save the matched parts for both search part($r->[0]) and replaced part($r->[1])?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "matched parts"? On the search, these are saved in $1, $2 etc. But a replacement doesn't have a matched part. So if $hex contains "8071C312345678775566", what do you consider to to be the values you want to save?

Comment: Your question is possibly a result of wrong approach to the original problem (which you didn't disclose here).

Comment: (a) > if $hex contains "8071C312345678775566", what do you consider to to be the values you want to save?
    Below are what I want to save:
    search part =>  8071C312345678775566
    repalce part => A0B0C012345678775566

(b) > On the search, these are saved in $1, $2 etc.
    I try 
    $s_sign = eval "\$hex =~ s/($r->[0])/$r->[1]/i";
    But both $1 and $& can't capture I want, would you give suggestion if only capture/save search part (8071C312345678775566)?

Thanks!

Comment: @mpapec

The search/replace really works, I used it for several years.

If I want to save the search part and replaced part, would you please give your suggestion how to modify the script? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, sorry, just found the solution, I complicated this simple problem.

Just need save $hex with $hex_tmp before replacement, when $s_sign = 1, then $hex_tmp is the search part, and $hex after replacement is the replaced part.

```
$search_32bit  = '80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66)';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'A0 B0 C0 \1\2';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

$search_32bit_2  = '60 71 C3 (\S{10}) (CC 55 66)';
$search_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit_2 = 'D0 E0 F0 \1\2';
$replace_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;

        @repls_32 = (
                [ $search_32bit, $replace_32bit],
                [ $search_32bit_2, $replace_32bit_2],
                );

$hex = "8071C312345678775566";

foreach my $r (@repls_32) {
        $hex_tmp = $hex;
        $s_sign = eval "\$hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/i";
        if ($s_sign) {
                print "search part: $hex_tmp\n";
                print "replaced part: $hex\n";
                exit();
        }
}
```

Below is the output I want.

search part: 8071C312345678775566
replaced part: A0B0C012345678775566

Answer (score 0):

Reference https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1006930, another sulution with /ee to replace 'eval'.

```
$search_32bit  = '80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66)';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'A0 B0 C0 .$1.$2';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

$search_32bit_2  = '60 71 C3 (\S{10}) (CC 55 66)';
$search_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit_2 = 'D0 E0 F0 .$1.$2';
$replace_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;

        @repls_32 = (
                [ $search_32bit, $replace_32bit],
                [ $search_32bit_2, $replace_32bit_2],
                );

$hex = "8071C312345678775566";

foreach my $r (@repls_32) {

        $hex_tmp = $hex;
        $s_sign = $hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/iee;
        if ($s_sign) {
                print "search part: $hex_tmp\n";
                print "replaced part: $hex\n";
                exit();
        }
}
```

Below get the same output.

search part: 8071C312345678775566
replaced part: A0B0C012345678775566

Answer (score 0):

If need capture the matched search part insead of whole string, can reference code below.

```
$search_32bit  = '(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))';
$search_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit = 'A0 B0 C0 \2\3';
$replace_32bit =~ s/\s+//g;

$search_32bit_2  = '60 71 C3 (\S{10}) (CC 55 66)';
$search_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;
$replace_32bit_2 = 'D0 E0 F0 .$1.$2';
$replace_32bit_2 =~ s/\s+//g;

        @repls_32 = (
                [ $search_32bit, $replace_32bit],
                [ $search_32bit_2, $replace_32bit_2],
                );

$hex = "9090908071C312345678775566";

foreach my $r (@repls_32) {

        $hex_tmp = $hex;
        $s_sign = eval "\$hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/i;return \$1";
        if ($s_sign) {
                print "search part: $s_sign\n";
                print "original:        $hex_tmp\n";
                print "replaced part:   $hex\n";
                exit();
        }
}
```

---

Please use "return $1" in regex as below, don't use $&, for the latter one is gobal variable, will meet issue for some complex case.

```
$s_sign = eval "\$hex =~ s/$r->[0]/$r->[1]/i;return \$1";
```

Accordingly，

```
    $search_32bit  = '80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66)';
=> 
    $search_32bit  = '(80 71 C3 (\S{8}) (77 55 66))';
```

Please notice the added outermost parentheses.

Hope this is helpful for guys who seek solution for similar issues.